# How can we get table indexes and related columns with sysindexes table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get defined indexes and related columns in my tables. I can do this by

```
sp_helpindex 'tableName'
```

but I want to get unique and non-unique indexes seperatly. How can we do this by writting a query on sysindexes table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `sys.indexes` view has a column `is_unique`:

```
select  i.name as IndexName
,       ic.key_ordinal as IndexColumnPosition
,       c.name as IndexColumnName
from    sys.indexes i
left join
        sys.index_columns ic
on      ic.object_id = i.object_id
        and ic.index_id = i.index_id
left join
        sys.columns c
on      c.object_id = ic.object_id
        and c.column_id = ic.column_id
where   i.object_id = object_id('YourTable')
        and i.is_unique = 1
```

Comment: @masoud ramezani: Yeah, just join on `index_columns`.  Example edited into answer.